# Your submission raised an exception of type NameError. This occurred on line 11 of your submission

Tags: python

```
word = input (" Enter the Word: ")
if word[0].isupper():
    word2 = word
elif word.endswith("s"):
    word2 = word[:-1]
elif word.endswith("ed"):
    word2 = word[:-2]
elif word.endswith("ing"):
    word2 = word[:-3]
if len(word2) <=2:
    print (word)
else:
    print(word2)
```

**Error - Your submission raised an exception of type NameError. This occurred on line 11 of your submission.**

Comment: You would get better responses here, if you did post a question (which some lines of code and an error message is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if word[0].isupper():`

If the first letter wasn't uppercase, then `word2` will have never been created. To prevent this, perhaps do:

```
word2 = ''
```

Before your conditionals. Now, even if the first letter is lowercase, you will not get a `NameError`, but `word2` will not be anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a cascade of `elif`s, always terminate them with an `else:`.  You might think that you have covered all possibilities in the `elif`s, in which case report an error.

Your problem is that you have not covered all possibilities, so add an `else`:

```
if word[0].isupper():
    word2 = word
elif word.endswith("s"):
    word2 = word[:-1]
elif word.endswith("ed"):
    word2 = word[:-2]
elif word.endswith("ing"):
    word2 = word[:-3]
else:
    word2 = ""
```